# command finished with non-zero exit value 1 intellij

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

while running the springboot application getting the following error:
`command 'D:/programs/openjdk-17.0.2_windows-x64_bin/jdk-17.0.2/bin/java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1`

The following are the ide logs:

```
   INFO - STDERR - Exception in thread "DisconnectableInputStream source reader" org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.nio.channels.AsynchronousCloseException
   INFO - STDERR -  at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:62)
   INFO - STDERR -  at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:41)
   INFO - STDERR -  at org.gradle.util.internal.DisconnectableInputStream$1.run(DisconnectableInputStream.java:127)
   INFO - STDERR -  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
   INFO - STDERR - Caused by: java.nio.channels.AsynchronousCloseException
   INFO - STDERR -  at java.base/java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:202)
   INFO - STDERR -  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.endRead(SocketChannelImpl.java:389)
   INFO - STDERR -  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:428)
   INFO - STDERR -  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SourceChannelImpl.read(SourceChannelImpl.java:113)
   INFO - STDERR -  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(ChannelInputStream.java:59)
   INFO - STDERR -  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(ChannelInputStream.java:107)
   INFO - STDERR -  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(ChannelInputStream.java:101)
   INFO - STDERR -  at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:282)
   INFO - STDERR -  at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:343)
   INFO - STDERR -  at org.gradle.util.internal.DisconnectableInputStream$1.run(DisconnectableInputStream.java:98)
```

using jdk 17 and gradle 7.4.1.

this is not heap issue as the heap memory allocated is 5GB and program has never exceeded it.

Comment: Error seems kinda generic. What exactly are you doing when you're getting it (running a specific Gradle Task, etc.)?  Would you be able to share the Project?

Comment: I enable the logging using deploy/application/log/log4j2-spring.xml and i get the issue.